# In C# ADO.NET, how can I tell if a sproc returned 0 rows versus the sproc had no commands to run on TSQL?

Tags: c#, t-sql, ado.net, sqldatareader

In C# ADO.NET, how can I tell if a sproc returned 0 rows versus the sproc had no commands to run on TSQL?

Let me lay it out in full. In TSQL I have (when I open this in SSMS)

```
ALTER PROC mySproc 
  @myvar VARCHAR(10)
AS

/* commented out on dev system - uncomment on production */
/* guess what didn't happen */
/* careful readers will note that we _normally_ 
   throw an exception when we do this. this sproc was missing said exception. */
```

When run in SSMS `mySproc 'value'` this says "Command(s) completed successfully." Under better circumstances (aka just no data returned but the body of the sproc is actually running), it would return what looked like a table but with no rows.

and in C#:

```
using( SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() ){
  //reader.HasRows == false
}
```

So, that's what I ran into, and without using "sql reflection" (ergo reading the actual script in the database) and without using an ORM (because then I would know that I was sending the right commands, but we have our reasons for using sprocs, of course) ...

How can I tell that I got a result of "Command(s) completed successfully." instead of a potential table with just no rows?

Comment: This sounds like a case of "don't do that".

Comment: @John I agree. I'm just thinking if I can be proactive. The dba responsible was already made to feel properly shamed today when I brought him to my desk and showed him the huge chunk of commented out text. Then we all got a laugh. I just want to throw an error next time.

Comment: Thats horrible but you could look at getting a count of the columns.  Something like reader.FieldCount > 0 or wrap reader.Item[0] in a try catch

Comment: @jcole: I think this is more of a people problem than a technology problem. Take steps to ensure you don't deploy garbage. See "[Starting Team Database Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193294.aspx)" for a tool within Visual Studio that brings database development up to the standards of other code development - including only deploying what's in source control.

Comment: @John ~ Yeah, alas, I'm really working to help get this sort of thing going in our org. Consider us fledgling team developers. I've so far got us on a DVCS with regular checkins and everyone understands how it works and how to merge, I've gotten my team to look past WebForms and static state management, so we're working on one thing at a time. If I could ONLY get them to move to VS for even 10% of the database development, but so far that has been as much a pipedream as you could wish for. One battle at a time, one fire at a time, yeah? +1 for people problem though. Spot on.

Comment: @Indigo I wish you would make that an answer for proper consideration ;) ...  I'm going to SERIOUSLY consider that in the future. It sounds like a completely viable solution to my problem. Quoting MSDN: `However. this should not be confused with a query that returns 0 rows (such as SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 = 2) in which case FieldCount returns the number of columns in the table, including hidden fields. Use VisibleFieldCount to exclude hidden fields.` Thanks!

Comment: @jcolebrand glad it helped.  I have pulled it out in to an answer so others can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I originally put this in a comment but it is more appropriate as an answer

You can use the `FieldCount` property on the reader to determine the number of columns.  For example:

```
using( SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() )
{
    if (reader.FieldCount > 0) 
    {
       // there are columns
    } 
    else 
    {
       // there are no columns, so stored proc returning no results set
    }
}
```

From [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.fieldcount.aspx) on `FieldCount`

> Executing a query that, by its nature, does not return rows (such as a DELETE query), sets FieldCount to 0. However. this should not be confused with a query that returns 0 rows (such as SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 = 2) in which case FieldCount returns the number of columns in the table, including hidden fields. Use VisibleFieldCount to exclude hidden fields.

Comment: Because this solution will help me in the future, I'm going to mark it accepted. It does do what I want. However, to be fair, I have not tried it in production, so it could be really slow or something. This is a note to the people that come along behind me. Feel free to leave comments!!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest auditing SQL Server and beating the crap out of developers that actually create SPROCs without bodies. I know of no way to determine stupidity in SQL Server from a reader other than actually issuing an audit when there are no rows (running something like sp_helptext and determine if there is a body?). It is hard to protect from sloppiness. Sorry!

Comment: I know. Sadly I'm _not_ one of the two full time DBAs, so I really can't do much more than scream and wave my hands. Fortunately I'm pretty well on my way to becoming the lead dev in this shop (with the former lead dev moving into PM or higher) so I can scream and get my way with only a little headbutting. I know that I can only give it time for now. ~ In the meantime, what do you think about Indigo's answer above in the comment about checking field counts?